# What is the purpose of setting web3.eth.Contract.defaultBlock?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blocks

In web3 object, the default value of web3.eth.Contract.defaultBlock is always "latest".
But what could be the case to modify defaultBlock value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- A block number: If you are making queries at certain height it might be useful to set the default to a block number. So all function will be consistent.
- 'pending': Perhaps you need to consider transactions that weren't mined yet, you set the default block to 'pending'.